# Vagrant error: VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is missing

Tags: vagrant

I want to "up" a vagrant box. But I get the following error:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.
```

My processor:

```
# lshw -class processor
  *-cpu                   
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU
       slot: U23
       size: 3200MHz
       capacity: 3200MHz
       width: 64 bits
       capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc pebs bts nopl pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
```

I also tried the Box `Debian squeeze 32` from http://vagrantbox.es with the same error message.

What can I try to use vagrant?

Answer (score 8):

If your CPU does not support VT-x, then you cannot run a guest 64 bit operating system. If a 32 bit guest OS still does not start with vagrant up, then you should specify the following in your Vagrantfile in order to turn hardware virtualization off for your vm:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb| 
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "off"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs of VirtualBox behind vagrant, if you have VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE (Intel) or VERR_SVM_IN_USE (Amd) message in it, that means there's something else using the processors virtualization capability.
For me, [HAXM](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) was that ugly guy (which is used for e.g. x86 based Android emulators)...

(I am using Windows 7)

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I wanted to set up the virtual box to be able to develop on a system that uses older libs than I had installed on my pc. Because I couldn't get that virtual box run I downgraded my system and solved that problem this way. Now I don't have the time to test your tip. But I think I will have the same problem in the future again. But my system is a debian wheezy with no such applications running, I think...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I had an old laptop using windows 8. This machine did not have the VT configuration on BIOS. My vagrant was not able to run, giving me the same issue. I went to control panel - programs and features. Then I unistall the feature "Hyper-V". Then I was able to run my VM via vagrant.

Because my old laptop was not even using this feature then I was ok with this solution.

Just putting this info out there, if this works for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If (as in my case) this wasn't anything to do with Hyper-V, it's worth checking your bios settings in case the Intel/AMD virtualization feature is disabled.  I had updated my bios recently, and it seems the VT-x feature was disabled.  Enabling it fixed the problem.

See BIOS settings section in:

https://www.itworld.com/article/2981515/virtualization/virtualbox-diagnose-and-fix-vt-xamd-v-hardware-acceleration-errors.html