# Failed to open/create the internal network Vagrant on Windows10

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10

I upgraded my Windows 10 to the last update yesterday and now, when I launch  `vagrant up` command, I get this error :

```
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

When I try with GUI I have this error :

```
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
```

I have re-installed VirtualBox 5.0.10 and the extension pack,
reconfigured Host-Only Ethernet Adapter, but always the same error...

Any ideas?

Comment: This helped me : https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14832#comment:20

Answer (score 514, accepted):

I found a solution

1. Open Windows Network Connections
2. Right click on VirtualBox Host only adapter that created
3. Choose properties
4. Check "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver"
5. disable and Enable the adapter

[image]

Comment: In my case it was just disabled.

Comment: I cannot believe it - was searching for this for hours. Was disabled for me, too. (Now, Genymotion as well as Xamarin Android Player can correctly create the interface. Somehow this broke during an update, and reinstalling VBox did not fix it.) Many thanks!

Comment: I bet you get a gold badge, for having not accepted answer :) However, you might not use Bridged adapter at all and this solution is not so universal. +1 for not needing reinstall.

Comment: It did not help me, moreover, it broke my chrome. To get Chrome working I updated the VirtualBox and rebooted computer. Chrome is working now again as it was, Edge - is not working.

Comment: It is amazing that 5 months later this issue still keeps coming back after every Virtualbox update. You would think that by now they worked out a solution...

Comment: Strange, when I installed 5.1.14, it is already disabled, and enabling it is the solutions.

Comment: I tried using Kitematic etc. none of these worked. Then I tried this .Thanks a ton!!

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was reinstall virtual box

Comment: In my laptop there is no built in Ethernet port. So after installing VM it won't adding host only adapter to adapter list. Then I tried it with my other laptop which having Ethernet port. It worked ! Because of this I couldn't run genemotion. If someone find solution for this let me know.

Comment: Worked for me, just in case if others are in the same boat as I am. I had to perform the above steps in Hyper-V virtual Ethernet Adapter, and other adapters like VirualBox host-only network#3 and Ethernet 5 - VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter(names might differ in your machine)... hope it helps.

Comment: This is helpful. Worked with windows 10 and Oracle VM virtualbox 6.0.10 perfectly

Comment: Worked for me (Windows 10 with VirtualBox 6.1.0 r135406).

Comment: Apparently this also happens when you install virtualbox but don't restart and try to open a VM.

Comment: It works, but it seems that we also have to disable and reenable the Host-Only adapter.

Comment: After I upgraded my win 10 to win 11 I got this error when I ran vagrant up. Your solution worked fine. tks

Comment: I had this problems after a windows update. For me, disabling, the enabling the adapter was all that I needed.

Comment: Same here after removing plenty of virtual host adapter created by VirtualBox. Thank you very much for your trick : disabling, then re-enabling was necessary for me

Comment: I was using ChatGPT for over a day and it could not solve this issue where the solution was so simple. Thanks

Comment: The title of the adapter didn't match the 'Connect using' "title" within the adapter, which is the one used in the error message. If you have multiple adapters, check the properties of each to find the one actually in use.

Answer (score 146):

There is a known issue with the new NDIS6 driver, you can install it to use the NDIS5 driver

Try reinstalling it with a parameter (**Run as administrator**)

`> VirtualBox-5.0.11-104101-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5`

This worked for me.

Update: Newer versions made it easier to pick the NDIS driver from within the installation wizard - just pick NDIS**5** when asked.

ref: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-win-performing

Comment: I've tried everything in this post and the only thing that worked for me was to downgrade VirtualBox to 4.2.22. Even 4.2.36 didn't work. S**t, lost a lot of time to this issue.

Comment: After following these steps, I received the error "Nonexistant host networking interface, name 'VirtualBox NDIS 6.0 Miniport Driver'.  I needed to then manually remove the associated Network adapters.

Comment: This did the trick for me too. Was having issues with Xamarin Android Player, which installs VM Ware for you

Comment: This is the real solution. I burned 4 hours of my time for this issue. I can eat my snacks now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks much :) I struggled for last 2 days to bring it back. I Have network adapter NDIS6. This was not at all working. So reinstalled VBox manually with option NDIS5 and it started working. 

My question is, even though my network device shown as NDIS6, I use NDIS5 during install. Does it cause any problems ?

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to get started with fabric8. Only this solution helped me with VirtualBox-5.0.22-108108-Win on Windows 8.1.

Comment: helped me to solve the issue with 5.0.24r108355 on Win8

Comment: Worked for me with VirtualBox 5.1.2 on Windows 7. Thanks a lot, dude!

Comment: Thank you... I am on VirtualBox 5.1.6 on Windows 7. This works!

Comment: Don't forget **Run as administrator** CMD

Answer (score 51):

- Open Network and Sharing Center and go to the Change adapter settings in the sidebar.
- Right-click on the host-only adapter in the list of adapters and then Configure button -> Driver tab -> Update driver button.
- Select Browse my computer ... and in the next dialog select Let me pick .... You should see the list with just host-only driver in it.
- Select it and click next. After the driver is updated, please try using host-only network in a VM again.

Comment: I don't know how  you figured this out, but thanks! This solved my problem.  5.2.14

Comment: This also worked on VirtualBox 6.0.10 after upgrading Windows from 1803 to 1809

Comment: This worked for me on VirtualBox 6.0.14 using minikube v1.3.1

Comment: This works for me when I update my vbox from 5.x to 6.1. Thanks.

Comment: Using Virtual Box 6.0.10 on Windows 10.0.19041.1 with the most recent updates, ran into this issue. After trying the all the other above options, this is the one which actually worked. Thank you !

Comment: This worked for me after upgrade to Windows10 (19042.631) , with VirtualBox 6.1.6.
Wondering how you figured this trick?

Comment: I faced the same problem after upgrading to Windows 10 21H2 and this helped me to overcome the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried above solutions and this was the only that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

I tried the above options, but in vain. Eventually I uninstalled docker-toolbox (1.11.x) and virtualbox(5.16.x) and CHECKED the following option in the docker-toolbox installer GUI (by default the NDIS5 option was unchecked)

[image: NDIS5 driver option unchecked]

Also the virtualadapter in network connections had "Bridge Networking Driver" option UNCHECKED and that worked fine for me

[image: Bridge Networking Driver option unchecked]

Comment: Works, Thanks a lot, I too have encountered this problem when trying to run Docker tools. Maybe it should be tagged as docker as well?

Comment: I had to do a couple of things before I was able to select this - first, manually install the VBox network driver .infs (browse to <vbox install dir>\Drivers\network, and install all the infs in the subfolders), and then second, I had to click the 'Install' button in the above dialog to manually add the VirtualBox (...) Networking Driver service (this is Windows 10).

Comment: This worked in my case. I tried disabling/reenabling the NDIS6 driver as suggested above, but it didn't help. What I ended up doing was uninstall VBox, grab Docker Toolbox 1.11.2 from GitHub (since the current installer 1.12.1 removes the checkbox options from the setup), and reinstall VBox with the NDIS5 option checked. Thanks!

Comment: I did just this but it didn't help me; until I found out that I also need to delete previously created network adapters. Also, don't forget to uninstall both Docker Toolbox and VirtualBox. Removing Docker Toolbox will not also remove VirtualBox. +1

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to this solution, I was able to leave the office. Thank you again.

Answer (score 33):

The same error occurred when I updated Windows.
Tried everything. Nothing worked.

Finally, went to Device Manager-> Network Adapters
Disabled and enabled the Virtualbox Host only Adapter

And it worked!

Comment: My VirtualBox adapters were both enabled already, but disabling and re-enabling them worked.

Comment: This worked, glad i found this solution in first go.

Answer (score 12):

### Restart your PC

---

Sadly, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733454/2191572 did not work for me in Windows 10 x64 with VirtualBox 5.2.6

The box was already checked and a simple restart fixed it.

After years of telling people to try restarting, I failed to follow my own golden advice; face, meet palm.

Comment: Had this issue after a Windows 10 update. A simple reboot did the trick form me as well :)

Comment: You saved me a lot time too.  Thanks

Comment: Oh man@#$ I spent 3 hrs doing absalutely nothing because it was all set up correctly, just had to reboot. Thanks, you should would for customer service IT department XD

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem after upgrading from `Windows 7` to `Windows 10`. Tried all the popular answers which did not work. Finally, I understood that Windows had changed the name of the adapter. `Virtual Box` was configured to use `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller` while device manager had this as `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2`. Selecting proper controller fixed the problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Last image helped a lot. I was looking the adaptor in Windows networks settings but adapter#2 was hidden, so I cannot restart it. I found it in device manager, unable-enable it and worked!

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall Virtualbox and install the latest version, at the time of this answer it's 5.12. I installed Vagrant which automatically installed Virtualbox 5.10. I ran into this issue after installing the Windows 1511 update, uninstalling the Vagrant provided Virtualbox and installing the latest version fixed this.

Comment: I installed update to 5.0.16 instead of 5.0.6 - it did not help, but it did not do worse either.

Comment: Same problem here, installing Virtualbox 5.1.6 solved it for me.

Comment: @ymajoros I am having this problem with 5.1.18.  Is there a way to get down to your version?

Answer (score 4):

The two answers did not solve my issue but combining them, I was able to solve the problem.
My situation was I was trying to install and run Docker on a Windows 7 pc and kept getting an error:
"Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue..."

After much digging, I was able to relate the issue to the host network adapter that was created by Docker.
I had the NDIS6 driver installed but it was enabled. I tried to uncheck, disable, recheck, enable etc but it did not help.

I then uninstalled VB and reinstalled as per the first answer to get the NDIS5 driver. 
This was unchecked, so checking it I was able to move past this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem with VirtualBox 5.1 on Windows 8. It turns out the problem was with the Kaspersky virus protection I have installed. It added the "Kaspersky Anti-Virus NDIS 6 Filter" on the host-only adapter on the windows side. When I disabled that filter the VM started properly:

[image: host-only network adapter properties]

Comment: In my case it was Avast .. and I uninstalled it from that properties window.. now its fine and working

Comment: Thank you for pointing to an antivirus! In my case it was Kaspersky Secure Connection tool installed (but disabled). After I uninstalled it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 4):

ON WINDOWS 10
After spending 3 frustrating hours of uninstalling & re-installing minikube, virtualbox that did not resolve the problem, I saw the network adapters in my
Control Panel->Network and Internet->Network Connections window.
There were 3 enabled "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" ones.
I disabled them all.
[image]
Then on services screen (run->services.msc) find the Tcp/Ip NetBIOS helper
and restart it.

A new network adapter with a proper name like "VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3" will be created.
Now type:
    minikube delete
    mnikube start
It worked for me.
hope It helped someone!
I hate this :)

Answer (score 3):

I have worked around for a while, all you need to do is open VirtualBox,

**File > Preferences** / **Network > Host-Only Networks**

You will see VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

click on it, and edit.

My IP settings for vagrant VM was 192.168.10.10, you should edit up to your VM IP

Here is my Network settings;

[image: Network Details: Adapter Settings]

[image: Network Details: DHCP Server Settings]

Answer (score 2):

I have Windows 8.1 and had this problem with VirtualBox 5.0.16.105871. I tried every suggestion I found here, virtual box site, and other forums. None worked for me. I had this error when tried to start a VM with host-only interface:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine LinuxVMDev0.

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Finally the only solution that worked for me was:

1. Uninstall 5.0.16
2. Install version 4.3.36 that did not have this problem (at least in my PC)
3. Without uninstalling 4.3.36, install version 5.0.16 in the default way

(Always installing as Administrator, i.e. running the installer as administrator).

That worked for me after trying different solution during days.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem, 
There was a conflict in my network adapters, I simply disabled the one who appears in the error message, then started again the running command, and a new adapter has been created after many approval messages from windows.

I hope this solution could help in some cases.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, but don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

If the accepted https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733454/8520387 doesn't work for you, then disable other enabled Ethernet Cards.
After this try to run your vagrant script again and it will create a new Network Card for you. For me it was #3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution was updating VirtualBox.

I first ran into this issue after fresh install of Docker toolbox(v1.12.5) on my Windows 8.1. What worked for me was update of VirtualBox. Then I had the same problem after some Windows Update, and updating VirtualBox fixed the issue again.

Comment: I simply updated VirtualBox to (current) version Version 5.2.4 r119785  and the problem went away ...

Answer (score 1):

Fo me, updating VirtualBox to 5.1.23 fixed the issue. You can download this version for Windows from the [official website](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.1.23-116680-Win.exe).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just do :

1- update  the Hyper-V  config like this picture.
[image]

2- reboot machine.

3- run  virtualbox

4- run vagrant up

Answer (score 0):

For me, disable and enable the network connection wasn't enough to make it work.
I had to delete the content of the .docker repository in my home user (c:/Users/your_user/.docker/).
After doing that i reinstall Docker Toolbox and VitualBox and use machzqcq tips to check the install virtualbox with NDIS5 driver.

I found the answer here : https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/473

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" on all but your actual physical network adapter(s) before attempting to create the VirtualBox host-only adapter again.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48227842/207981).

Answer (score 0):

After a Windows 10 update my **VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter** was actually gone from the OS' network adapters (view these under *Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings*). Had to reinstall VirtualBox to bring that back to the OS.

Then in the newer version of VirtualBox, the host-only adapters are under *Global Tools (top right) -> Host Network Manager*. Make sure the DHCP Server is enabled for the adapter.

Example config:
[image]

Comment: I went into these settings via `File>Host Network Manager`, then I removed and recreated the problematic network. I just let it create with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every single thing on this page (and thanks everyone!).  Nothing worked.  After literally hours and hours, I finally got it working.

My problem was that I had no error preceding "something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´".

This line in the start.sh script failed.

```
VM_STATUS="$( set +e ; "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" status "${VM}" )"
```

Running the following line from the Command Prompt worked and returned "Running".

```
D:\Dev\DockerToolbox\docker-machine.exe status default
```

So I started following all the fixes in [Github link](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/473) and found the fix.

In the start.sh script, I changed the line

```
VM_STATUS="$( set +e ; "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" status "${VM}" )"
```

to

```
VM_STATUS="$(${DOCKER_MACHINE} status ${VM})"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Open Control Panel >> Network and Sharing Center. Now click on Change Adapter Settings. Right click on the adapter whose Name or the Device Name matches with VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter # 3 and click on Properties. Click on the Configure button.
>
> Now click on the Driver tab. Click on Update Driver. Select Browse my
> computer for drivers. Now choose Let me pick from a list of available
> drivers on my computer. Select the choice you get and click on Next.
> Click Close to finish the update. Now go back to your
> Terminal/Powershell/Command window and repeat the vagrant up command.
> It should work fine this time.

https://www.howtoforge.com/setup-a-local-wordpress-development-environment-with-vagrant/

Answer (score 0):

for me, I had to delete the .virtualbox & .docker folder In my user directory... which worked out fine