# Docker Quickstart Terminal fails to start VirtualBox VM in Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-toolbox

I've tried several times to start the Docker VM via the Docker Quickstart Terminal. After deleting the `default` virtual machine in VirtualBox I receive the following output

```
Creating Machine default...
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) OUT | Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) OUT | Creating SSH key...
(default) OUT | Starting VirtualBox VM...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

To troubleshoot further, I attempted to start the `default` machine in the VirtualBox GUI directly using Start > Headless Start, as suggested in other Docker issues. The startup failed and I received an error dialog box with the content:

```
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code:

E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Component:

ConsoleWrap

Interface:

IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Versions of related components:

- VirtualBox Version 5.0.11 r104393
- Docker Toolbox 1.9.1a
- Windows 10 Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.14)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10) question solved my problem. Here it is with a few edits:

> I found a solution
>
> 1. Open Windows Network Connections
> 2. Right click on VirtualBox Host only adapter that was created
> 3. Choose properties
> 4. Check "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver"
> 5. Disable and Enable the highlighted item
>
> [image: Adapter properties]

For me "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" was not checked. I checked it and clicked OK to close the Properties window. After that, the Docker Quickstart Terminal was able to start the VM successfully.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I had three VirtualBox Host only adapters in Windows Network Connections. I had to do these steps on the correct one before it worked, which took a few attempts.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me. At this moment I am using Windows Home.

At least in my case, what happened was that the environment variables **DOCKER_MACHINE** and **DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH** were not created for the system.

I just had to add them and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow @chris-hunt answer, but I didn't found the highlighted item. I realized it was due to the fact I didn't installed the VirtualBOX that comes in the Docket Tools installation. I think I was using an older version.
So I uninstalled docker tools AND  VitualBOX, both on windows Control Panel. After that, I reinstalled Docker Tools with the VirtualBOX checked, and it finally worked.