# Run command vagrant up and get default: warning: connection timeout. Retrying

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, vagrant, homestead

I have looked at some of the other post about this and half of the stuff they say makes 0 since to me or the commands they say to run in the terminal come back as command not found. I have a windows OS so that could be the problem. If you run into this problem with windows please help!

I have disabled the firewall and that did nothing.

Vagrantfile:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

Comment: I use vagrant on a Windows host. Can you please paste your VagrantFile?

Comment: Is that within the homestead folder and if so I will put it on the post

Comment: What windows version? What Wm software? How does your vagrant file look like? Enable debug and post the errors

Comment: Windows 10, not sure what you mean wm software, and I posted the file on the post so you can see now.

Comment: Oh this is homestead.  VMWare or VirtualBox? And please enable debug in vagrant and post that too

Comment: Using virtualbox and how do I enable debug in vb sorry this is my very first time with this.

Comment: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging  please Google next time

Comment: Okay I ran vagrant up --debug and now it is stuck on DEBUG subprocess: waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0

Comment: I am fairly sure that virtualbox does not work without some tweakings on windows 10. I know VMWare works, but that's not free.

Comment: Okay so i'm guess you don't know the tweakings =/?

Comment: @samuidavid Have you looked at this ? and could you help?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/33733454/4296747

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Did not work still getting same error

Comment: humm .. can you start the VM from virtual box ? does it work ok ?

Comment: I never tried that but no I cannot it says 
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
SessionMachine
Interface: 
ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}

Comment: Also something else I have noticed is that under my network connections now I have mutliple virtualBox: Host-only networks

Comment: @FrédéricHenri    Okay if I run as admin I can open it but then I get this : VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.

Answer (score 0):

ok as the issue is linked with *VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration*  you should have 2 options:

1. Enable virtualization from your bios if your hardware supports it (it might be turn off in your settings)
2. If your hardware/CPU does not support it, tell vagrant to turn off hw virtualization by adding this in your Vagrantfile

   ```
   config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb| 
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "off"]
   end
   ```

something like

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb| 
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "off"]
    end
end
```

Comment: Where do I put this in the vagrantfile? I dont think this is working though thanks for the feedback. I will just continue without using vb/homestead at this point.

Comment: add example with your vagrantfile, did you also check your bios settings?