# Xamarin: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Nexus 7 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Xamarin Andriod player  for VS 2015,

[image]

I looked into this error and I think it is due to virtualization being disabled in windows BIOS. I have enabled and tried again, still it is exists. I have checked the Xamarin VS log. It is shown error as:

```
 Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Nexus 7 (Lollipop).

 Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

 Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
```

I am not sure what to do next to fix this, could some one help me please?

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for possible solution for Windows 7 x64

Comment: do you have another Emulator installed ? or did previously installed? like "genymotion"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Open Windows Network Connections
2. Right click on VirtualBox Host only adapter that created
3. Choose properties
4. Check "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver"
5. disable and Enable the adapter

[image]

Comment: I have tried this already.. but not worked.. getting some error "VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND"

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10) which includes several answers. It refers to `Vagrant`, but since the error message is the same, I think it's worth giving it a try.

Regarding Windows 7 and in case solutions provided in the first link don't work, here is a [VirtualBox official forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=64029#p305603) workaround for the same error message:

> Go to Device Manager --> Network adapters --> Uninstall network adapter (on which setting Bridged adapter is not working) --> Click on Scan for harware changes --> Restart PC --> after restart go to Device Manager --> Network adapters --> uninstalled network adapter will be marked with "!", again uninstall this network adapter --> Click on Scan for harware changes - now network adapter will be installed and restart will not be required. It is all, test Bridged adapter in VirtualBox ...

It seems to work on Windows 7 environments, as it worked for many users.

Comment: I have tried this steps.. I am unable to find the driver adapter after restarting the system.. step stopped at "-> will be marked with "!" "

Comment: In this case, then proceed to Click on Scan for hardware. If it is not found, reinstall your network adapter.

Comment: By the way, did you try the "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver" method which I also referenced? Solution was valid for Windows 10, but it may work for Windows 7

Comment: Trid but getting this error now.. "VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND" failed to open internal network

Comment: Try to uninstall first and then install your driver as Administrator

Comment: Look at the first comment here, there's another workaround that you can try: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14604#comment:1 (Network & Sharing Center --> Change adapter settings in the sidebar. Right-click on the host-only adapter in the list of adapters --> Configure button --> Driver tab --> Update driver button. --> Browse my computer --> Let me pick .... You should see the list with just host-only driver in it. Select it and click next. After the driver is updated, please try using host-only network in a VM again.

Comment: still it is failed.. getting same as mentioned in my question. can you help online chatting..