# Virtual Box cannot rename this connection error on installation

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I'm on Windows 7 and when I install Virtual Box 5.1.26-117224, I get `Cannot rename this connection. A connection with the name you specified already exists. Specify a different name.` . I've tried the many solutions online to no avail. I've tried deleting all connections, hidden connections re-installing etc but I get the same error every time.

running `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" hostonlyif create`

gives me:-

```
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tind
erbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (74) in lon
g __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Bstr,class com::Bstr,class com::
Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0038).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Please contact the product vendor!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkI
nterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct Han
dlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp`
```

I might just format the OS at this point, I'd rather not though. From what I've read all the solutions seem to date back to 2015 and seem to relate to Windows 10 - not Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried a fresh reinstall?

Comment: Yes I've tried that but get the same error.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10

Comment: Already read that and tried all of those with no joy :/

Comment: Tried deleting all the networks in the network manager except your ethernet and Wi-Fi once