# Vagrant error when running vagrant up on Git Bash on Window 10

Tags: bash, server, vagrant, virtualbox

I am having trouble with vagrant up on Git Bash.
I'm currently using Vagrant 2.2.19 and VirtualBox 6.1 version.
Whenever I put vagrant up on Bash to be able to open VirtualBox server on Git bash using vagrant ssh, it shows the following error.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/bionic64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20200304.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: profiles-rest-api_default_1644116739589_78823
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

- What I have done so far

- Visualization is enabled from BIOS
- Install VirtualBox extension pack
- Uninstall and reinstall VirtualBox and Vagrant several times

Also, when I put vagrant ssh after that error, it shows nothing, but the VirtualBox is running as this image. Can you guys help me figure out how to open the VirtualBox server on Bash, please? Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwpOm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9023) useful link.
-Try to downgrade the vagrant version that you are using and try again.
-Also, try to use the command `debug vagrant up` in order to have debug logs available for a more precise description of the error message.

Finally, take a look at [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419563/vagrant-up-error-in-headless-ubuntu-the-guest-machine-entered-an-invalid-state) too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade the virtualbox version and the vagrant version (they need to be both on convenient versions)